# Mysql does not request password in remote connections

Tags: mysql

my problem is the following, I need to create a user with full administrator control over all the DBs that I have on the server, and be able to connect externally from my LAN with the created user.

I have managed to create the user and assign them all permissions so that they can operate without restrictions. In the following way:

```
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
CREATE USER 'myuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

Grant all privileges:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

I modify the directive in my.cnf

```
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

I can connect remotely from any point on my LAN in the following way:

```
REMOTECLIENT# mysql -u $MYUSER -h $HOST -P 3306 -D $MYDB
```

I can authenticate without problems, but it does not require me to use the user's password, I log in automatically, I don't want that.

If I enter the user's password I get an error:

> ```
> REMOTECLIENT# mysql -u $MYUSER -h $HOST -P 3306 -D $MYDB --password 'mypass'
> Enter password:
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user '$MYUSER@$HOST' (using password: YES)
> ```

What is the reason for this behavior, did I leave any directives to add in my.cnf or is it due to some privilege?

```
MYSQL ver: 8.0.32

OS: Oracle Linux 8
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Does your password have any special characters that are interpreted by the shell? Some characters are still metacharacters to the shell even inside single-quotes. You could try entering your password interactively, just use `mysql -p` and it will prompt you to type it in.

Comment: As for the client allowing you to log in without entering a password, I would look for a the password in the `~/.my.cnf` file, or `~/.mylogin`, or `/etc/my.cnf`. Also the `MYSQL_PWD` environment variable may be set.

Comment: My problem is not the opposite, I can access the server from any point on my network with my user without credentials. That is, without the -p command, I want the exact opposite that the password be required to connect.

Comment: Okay, try this experiment: connect as your user without the password. In the MySQL client, run `SHOW CREATE USER CURRENT_USER;`. Does it show a password hash? Or no password hash?

Comment: I think you found the reason why, there is no hash, and I have seen a directive that gives me a bad feeling: `CREATE USER user@% IDENTIFIED WITH 'mysql_native_password' REQUIRE NONE PASSWORD EXPIRE DEFAULT ACCOUNT UNLOCK PASSWORD HISTORY DEFAULT PASSWORD REUSE INTERVAL DEFAULT PASSWORD REQUIRE CURRENT DEFAULT`

Comment: Looks like you created the user with no password, despite your example CREATE USER statement at the top of your post above. I suggest you set a password for the user. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html

Comment: Solved, changing the password again solves the problem `ALTER USER "user"@"%" IDENTIFIED BY "pass"`, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the troubleshooting in the comment thread above, it was discovered that despite the `CREATE USER` statements, somehow the user had been created with no password.

Setting the password using `ALTER USER` resolved the problem.